# How do I select an option using Spring's form:select tag?

Tags: spring, forms, select

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  Using the form:select tag, how do I specify which option should be selected?  I want the first one to be selected, but when I put

```
            <form:select path="parentOrganization">
                <form:option value="" label="Select an Org Type or Parent Org" />
                <form:options items="${orgTypesWoParents}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="description" />
                <form:option value="" label="=======================" />
            </form:select>
```

the last one is selected.  I want to preserve the order of how everything is displayed, which is why I've arranged things in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <form:select path="parentOrganization">
            <form:option value="" selected="selected" label="Select an Org Type or Parent Org" />
            <form:options items="${orgTypesWoParents}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="description" />
            <form:option value="" label="=======================" />
        </form:select>
```